# Cinnamon, System Settings, Windows: Right side title bar button: 'Sticky'?

Tags: cinnamon, theme

In the Cinnamon desktop, if you open `System Settings`> `Windows`, you can then set the

**`Right side title bar buttons`**

---

There are 6 choices for each button:

- **Menu**        -Shows pull down menu
- **Close**       -Closes and exits the window
- **Minimize**    -Closes the widow, but keeps it open in the panel
- **Maximize**    -Toggles window between full screen and partial screen
- **Sticky**      -?
- **Shade**       -Toggles window between normal & folded showing only title bar

**What does Sticky do?**

---

The sticky button icon (configured 4th from left below) toggles.

It looks like this before being clicked

[image]

and after being clicked:

[image]

---

**Tips:**

- Not all buttons appear (are visible) for all `System Settings`> `Themes`> `Window borders` settings. However if you set the `Window borders` to `Bluebird` you can see all button icons, e.g. 2 left and 4 right buttons. (In fact, **`Bluebird` appears to be the only `Window borders` setting that shows all of the button icons**.  *(However some of the other settings show a custom icon for the Menu button which is nice, and do other things nicely that may also appeal to you.  For me I prefer to get all of the buttons.  GreenLaguna and BlackMATE also show all of the buttons, but don't show icons, but rather when you hover over them they have different colors, neat, but confusing I think.)*
- Even if some buttons are invisible (e.g. because the theme is set to something other than Bluebird), they still seem to function when blindly clicked.

---

I'm running: Cinnamon version 3.2.7, on Debian 9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Sticky is toggled on the window appears on all Workspaces, i.e. not just the current Workspace.

---

You can also adjust Sticky by clicking the Menu icon in the title bar (i.e. the down arrow w/ bar above it icon):

[image]

and then select either 'Always on Visible Workspace' OR 'Only on This Workspace', here:

[image]